# Angular component seems to be sharing state with all instances

Tags: angular

Angular component seems to be sharing state with all instances. I made a demo that shows the issue. My file upload updates the topmost instance instead of the instance that I click. Thx  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-instance-output?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all files has the same id,

So you have to remove id attr from your html

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label *ngIf="!fileData" (click)="fileInput.click()" class="custom-file-upload">
                      <i class="flaticon-attachment icon"></i> Attach Supporting File ...
                  </label>
                  <input #fileInput  type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event.target.files[0])"/>
                  <label #fileInputLabel class="file-name-label">{{fileName}}</label>
                  <button #fileInputRemove *ngIf="fileData" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-send" (click)="onRemoveFile()">Remove Attachment</button>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. It's fixed now.